# How to determine when the cells in a tableView are returned so as to add a uiview after its finished?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, nstableheaderview

I'm working with some legacy code and it looks like they added a custom sticky header view in the viewDidLoad.  The issues is that I need to add the sticky header view AFTER the other cells are returned so that I may send the sticky header view to the back of the other cells so it can be used as a background for the topmost cell.

like so:

```
 homeScreenTableView.sendSubviewToBack(headerView)
```

or

```
homeScreenTableView.insertSubview(headerView, at: 0)
```

The issue is there is no call back after the cells are returned in a tableView. I know this is a bit hacky, but is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just add the view behind the tableview rather than a specific cell?

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried that approach initially, its because its a sticky header and has specific behavior when scrolling.

Comment: You can use another design for topmost cell, or if your header is not a complex view you can just add all of your cells and hide/show when you return your cell in `cellForRowAt` method

Answer (score 0):

You check if the last indexPath in indexPathsForVisibleRows array has been displayed on screen.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let lastVisibleIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last {
        if indexPath == lastVisibleIndexPath {
            // finished loading
        }
    }
}
```